# Does a caching-nameserver usually cache the negative DNS response SERVFAIL

Tags: dns

Does a caching-nameserver usually cache the negative DNS response SERVFAIL?

EDIT:
To clarify the question, I can see the caching nameserver caching negative responses NXDOMAIN, NODATA. But it does not do this for SERVFAIL responses. Is this intentional?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SERVFAIL is covered by §7.1 of RFC2308:

> Server failures fall into two major
>   classes.  The first is where a 
>   server can determine that it has been
>   misconfigured for a zone.  This may
>   be where it has been listed as a server, but not configured to be    a
>   server for the zone, or where it has
>   been configured to be a server    for
>   the zone, but cannot obtain the zone
>   data for some reason.  This    can
>   occur either because the zone file
>   does not exist or contains    errors,
>   or because another server from which
>   the zone should have    been available
>   either did not respond or was unable
>   or unwilling to    supply the zone.
>
> The second class is where the
>   server needs to obtain an answer from 
>   elsewhere, but is unable to do so, due
>   to network failures, other    servers
>   that don't reply, or return server
>   failure errors, or    similar.
>
> In either case a resolver MAY cache
>   a server failure response.  If it 
>   does so it MUST NOT cache it for
>   longer than five (5) minutes, and it 
>   MUST be cached against the specific
>   query tuple <query name, type, 
>   class, server IP address>.

So basically, it's dependent on the implementation of your name server.

Answer (score 3):

[RFC 1034](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1034.html) describes how to cache negative responses but did not define a mechanism for returning those cache results to peer resolvers. [RFC 2308](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2308.html) defines these attributes.

Negative caching was an optional part of the DNS Specifications...

Answer (score 0):

One of the timeout fields in the SOA is a "negative timeout". It is usually set to a short time, such as 30 or 60 seconds. So, yes, but for a shorter time than a "positive" response.

Comment: No SOA record is returned with a SERVFAIL response, so there is no TTL, and no cache time set by the server. However, if the server responds with a NODATA record, it should include an SOA record for the domain, with a TTL, which will be cached.